# Android table-layout not rendering real-time

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to android facing a UI update problem.

I have some TextViews and EditText widgets in rows of a table-layout.

When the user clicks on an item on a list, I want to populate the details of that item into this table.

I believe my code for updating the edittext widgets is working find and I can see that it has been updated.

However,I observe the table-row becomes blank on an update and when I click on the edittext, only then can I see the updated text (I guess I can see updated text only on onFocus() or something).

Could someone please tell me why does it behave this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you update the view use another thread and call invalidate();

```
yourEditText.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourEditText.setText("your text");
                yourEditText.invalidate();
            }
        });
```